# No '/' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSNumber'

Tags: swift3

I just update to swift 3 and got this issue.

[image: issue]

```
let percentString = NumberFormatter.localizedString(
        from: Double(correctGuesses) / Double(totalGuesses),
        number: NumberFormatter.Style.percent)
```

Comment: Please post your code as text as well. Makes it easier to read and reference when answering.

Comment: @rmaddy done, edited

Comment: Adding `as NSNumber` should help, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39321421/working-with-nsnumber-integer-values-in-swift-3 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493898/nsexpression-nsnumber-extension-changed-in-swift-3-0

Comment: @MartinR yes it did, pls post your answer to mark it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var correctGuesses = 10
var totalGuesses = 20

var result = NSNumber(value: correctGuesses / totalGuesses)

let percentString = NumberFormatter.localizedString(
  from: result,
  number: NumberFormatter.Style.percent
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Or simply, for not add another var

```
let percentString = NumberFormatter.localizedString(
from: NSNumber(value: Double(correctGuesses) / Double(totalGuesses)),
number: NumberFormatter.Style.percent)
```